# "Replace the position of the object" vs. "replace the object"

Tags: word-usage, writing

How should I write «*replace the position of the object*» or «*replace the object*» will be enough and the first variant is verbose?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're saying to get rid of an object and fill its place with a new one, then you would use the second one (*replace the object*).

If you're saying to move the object (change its position) you would modify the first sentence to make it ***reposition*** the object.

Comment: ... or "change the position". At any rate, "replace the position" makes zero sense.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Indeed.